# Darken menu bar when pop up is active

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, design, top-bar

Pop ups are currently just being placed on top of the content, not the menu bar.

**Is this how a page pop up should work, or should it actually be placed on top of all content?**

**Vimeo** (upload video), **imgur** (new post), **Google+** (what's new with you?), **Instagram** (user more details) are all placing their popups on top of ALL the page.

This affects both sticky and non-sticky header.

When adding a new link (notice the white header):

[image: add link]

When uploading an image (again, notice the white header):

[image: upload image]

---

Also, what about code snippets? They don't seem to be follow the others convention.

[image: add code snippet]

Comment: All dialogs are eventually going to be indistinguishable from the Windows UAC elevation prompt.

Comment: It's a bug. Header should not be above overlay. We will fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) Fix for this issue is waiting in repo and should be live after next build. Thanks for reporting.